# How can I generate the sequence of Kvalues for CORDIC?

Tags: c, algorithm, matlab, trigonometry, cordic

I am trying to implement [CORDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC) in C. I have to generate the constant values that the algorithm uses. The first list of arctangent values was straightforward but I am having trouble with the second list of *'Kvalues.'*

> ```matlab
> % Kvalues = cumprod(1./sqrt(1 + 1j*2.^(-(0:23))))
> Kvalues = [ ...
>    0.70710678118655   0.63245553203368   0.61357199107790   0.60883391251775 ...
>    0.60764825625617   0.60735177014130   0.60727764409353   0.60725911229889 ...
>    0.60725447933256   0.60725332108988   0.60725303152913   0.60725295913894 ...
>    0.60725294104140   0.60725293651701   0.60725293538591   0.60725293510314 ...
>    0.60725293503245   0.60725293501477   0.60725293501035   0.60725293500925 ...
>    0.60725293500897   0.60725293500890   0.60725293500889   0.60725293500888 ];
> ```

However I am not very familiar with this notation and I am having a hard time making sense of this and producing a simple formula that would produce the same results. I do not want to just paste these values into my CORDIC implementation because I would like to generate them myself with the appropriate amount of precision.

Here is what I came up with based on what I could understand but this does not produce the correct results:

```c
float prev = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < PRECISION; i++)
    printf("%f\n", prev = prev/sqrt(1+pow(2, -i)));
```

I am expecting the same values I saw in the list from Wikipedia:

```
0.707106
0.632455
0.613571
0.608833
0.607648
0.607351
```

But with my formula they converge to `0.457942...` instead of `0.607252...`:

```
0.707107
0.577350
0.516398
0.486864
0.472328
0.465116
```

What is the correct formula in C to generate `PRECISION` *'Kvalues'* for CORDIC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried a number of variations [not shown] by doing a websearch on `CORDIC` and looking at various pages.

From here: https://nonagon.org/ExLibris/cordic-c-javascript I got the formula:

```
prev = prev / sqrt(1 + (1.0 / pow(2, 2.0 * i)))
```

Ultimately, for your code, it was change:

```
pow(2, -i)
```

Into:

```
pow(2, -2.0 * i)
```

---

Here is the modified code that works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PRECISION   6

#define CALL(_fnc) \
    do { \
        printf("\n" #_fnc "\n"); \
        _fnc(); \
    } while (0)

void
orig(void)
{
    double prev = 1.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < PRECISION; i++)
        printf("%f\n", prev = prev / sqrt(1 + pow(2, -i)));
}

void
fix1(void)
{
    float prev = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < PRECISION; i++)
        printf("%f\n",prev = prev / sqrt(1 + pow(2, -2.0 * i)));
}

int
main(void)
{

    CALL(orig);
    CALL(fix1);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the program output:

```
orig
0.707107
0.577350
0.516398
0.486864
0.472328
0.465116

fix1
0.707107
0.632456
0.613572
0.608834
0.607648
0.607352
```

---

I recommend using `double` instead of `float` and increasing the precision of the `printf` format (e.g. `%.14f`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PRECISION   6

#define CALL(_fnc) \
    do { \
        printf("\n" #_fnc "\n"); \
        _fnc(); \
    } while (0)

void
orig(void)
{
    double prev = 1.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < PRECISION; i++)
        printf("%.14f\n", prev = prev / sqrt(1 + pow(2, -i)));
}

void
fix1(void)
{
    double prev = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < PRECISION; i++)
        printf("%.14f\n",prev = prev / sqrt(1 + pow(2, -2.0 * i)));
}

int
main(void)
{

    CALL(orig);
    CALL(fix1);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the enhanced output:

```
orig
0.70710678118655
0.57735026918963
0.51639777949432
0.48686449556015
0.47232793895472
0.46511640189705

fix1
0.70710678118655
0.63245553203368
0.61357199107790
0.60883391251775
0.60764825625617
0.60735177014130
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that formula was using using the imaginary unit `1j` and complex numbers to obtain the length of the vector. Another way is to simply use the Pythagorean theorem directly, which would drop the `1j` part and square the `2.^(-(0:23))` term instead.

Doubling the base of the `pow()` achieves this effect:

```c
float prev = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < PRECISION; i++)
    printf("%f\n", prev = prev/sqrt(1+pow(/* 2 */ 4, -i)));
```

Output:

```
0.707107
0.632456
0.613572
0.608834
0.607648
0.607352
...
```

Comment: `float prev` makes little sense here as `prev/sqrt(...)` converts `prev` to a `double`, then divides, then converts quotient to `float`, then convert `prev` to `double` to pass to `printf()`.  Recommend `double prev` .